# Transfer a Qt mouse (drag) event on child widget to parent

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to map a click and drag even on a child widget to its parent. Specifically, I'd like `MyWidget` to move when I drag `MyButton` in the example below:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>

class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    MyButton( QWidget *parent ) : QPushButton( parent )
    {
    }
};

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget( QWidget *parent = NULL ) : QWidget( parent ) , button( this )
    {
        setFixedSize( 300 , 150 );
        button.setText( "Button" );
        button.setGeometry( 25, 25 , 250 , 100 );
    }

private:
    MyButton button;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to implement this, although I am currently considering having `MyButton` forward the mouse event to `MyWidget`.

Comment: Use `c++` tag always when you ask about C++, it's quite popular and many people with Qt experience probably don't follow `qt` tag. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `MyButton` as a friend class in `MyWidget` and then forward `MyButton::mousePressEvent` to `MyWidget::mousePressEvent`, and similarly for drag event. If you have more events to forward and don't want to implement many unnecessary methods in `MyButton`, you can reimplement `QWidget::event` in `MyButton` and forward specific events to `MyWidget::event`. In such case, remember to call `QWidget::event` explicite for events that you don't handle.

Comment: You shouldn't have to 'friend' it; just call parent() in any MyButton methods to forward the call.

Comment: @Scott Those methods are protected, I though you have to be a friend to call them. You are, of course, right about calling parent(), that's what I meant by saying 'forward'.

Comment: I've been calling `QApplication::sendEvent( parentWidget , (QEvent*) event );` in the child widget event handler. Is this equivalent to calling `parent()`